# plotting 100k latitude-longitude locations on map

Tags: google-maps, csv, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have about 100k locations stored in a MySQL server.

I want to plot this in a map, but when I export it to a .csv file and then convert to .kml file, the file size exceeds 20mb, whereas Google Map API has limits of 3mb for .kml file.
The .csv file is about 2.5mb, but I cannot load .csv files into Google Map.

Is there any way I can do load the locations to a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Google Fusion Tables - they support 100,000 points per layer and 5 layers *in toto*. They are lightning fast too as you access them via an SQL-type language that runs on Google's servers - exactly where your data will be when you upload it.

You load your CSV into a Fusion Table in your Google drive and get a key to that table and you then use the key in your Javascript.

I created the following website with Fusion Tables and I am a zero in Javascript! See Skyscan website [here](http://www.skyscan.co.uk/mapsearch).

Comment: I haven't used the API yet, and I have a question. What do you mean by getting a 'key'? You mean the link? Can you provide me with a snippet of the code where you used the key to the fusion table? Thanks.

Comment: Just use the "View Source" option in your web browser. Alt-Cmd-U on a Mac. Ctrl-U in Firefox. Or look for "Developer Tools" in your browser's menus.

Comment: Maybe F12 in Internet Explorer? Not sure.

Comment: Is lines 43 ~ 47 the part you are using the keys?

Comment: Oh nevermind. fusion tables automatically plotted the points in the map. how convenient!