# Draw million markers on static map

Tags: html, google-maps, canvas

I want to draw map that looks like this image:

[image]

On this map one marker is one blue dot and there are million of markers. The map is static, just image.

P.S.: Url size limit of google static maps api makes it useless.

Comment: "Map" tag save like "dictionary", looks like bug.

Comment: not  a bug, it thinks you are talking about a data collection map. added some tags so people can suggest answers using html and canvas

Comment: Static Map is a no go for 1mil markers, for many reasons. -- however run this demo i created and wait and see if it hits 1mill -- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEKNbg

Comment: Static map is good, trust me and watch the last update to the question.

Comment: See my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762568/plotting-100k-latitude-longitude-locations-on-map/21762889#21762889 If your map is static, I presume you could do it in 2 halves with 500,000 points each.

Answer (score 1):

**Your (red) map has only a fraction of a million uniquely visible indicators.**

This means thousands (if not most) of your indicators have dozens of other indicators that are directly on top of each other.

**So your first step is to remove duplicate indicators.**

If your data does not change over a modest time, you can de-dupe your data on the server--or better yet, de-dupe on the computer that originated the data.

Once your data has been de-duped, canvas can render your remaining points quickly:

For example, here's your 509x283 image with 1000000/12==83333 one-by-one sized squares.  Rendering these 83333 indicators took 341ms on my modestly powered computer.

[image]

...And rendering your 2 873 379 indicators (de-duped to 2873379/12==239449) took 913ms.

[image]

...But notice the above (dupsX12) canvas is almost completely filled with color, so it's likely that your data has many more than 12X duplicates. Here's your 2873379 indicators assuming 200X duplicates (14367 unique indicators) which in my (poor) estimation fills up about the same percentage of space as your red map. This was rendered in 57ms.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be taking the wrong approach here. You want all markers visiable? all 1 million? if those markers are 1px each and still show the map image?, how big's your monitor?

I'd suggest you look back at google maps and maybe a smarter way of showing, such as showing a number of locations on higher zoom levels then showing more markers when the user zooms in

[here is the google maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?csw=1) they show how to have ranges and markers with counters inside as well as change markers visible on different zoom levels

Comment: Yes, all 1 million visible, but markers can overlap each other. I know about clusterization, i know about showing count of markers instead of markers, but I want to draw just pixels like I said before.

Comment: Changed map picture for better understading

Answer (score 0):

This PHP code generates static image:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = imagecreatefrompng('staticmap.png');
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);
$w=-179.0;//world borders
$s=-56.6;
$e=179.0;
$n=78.2;

$c = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);

$cursor = ...;//query to database
foreach($cursor as $iter) 
{
    $p = $iter['geoPoint'];
    $lon = (double)$p['lon'];
    $lat = (double)$p['lat'];   

    $x = ((-$w+$lon)*$width)/(-$w+$e);
    $y = (($n-$lat)*$height)/(-$s+$n);

    imagefilledellipse ( $im , $x , $y , 3 , 3 , $c);
} 

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

There is no need to use projections to draw the map. Thats why there is no need to use any API.